Semi definite inner product is either positive or negative inner product
According to nlab's definition of inner product
( see : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inner+product+space ),
inner product is defined on vector space over field with involution. And it satisfies :

$\langle0, x\rangle = 0$ and $\langle x, 0\rangle = 0$
$\langle x + y, z \rangle = \langle x, z \rangle + \langle y, z\rangle$ and $\langle x, y + z \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle + \langle x, z \rangle$
$\langle cx, y \rangle = c'\langle x, y \rangle$ and $\langle x, cy \rangle = c \langle x, y \rangle$ ( here, $'$ means result of involution of that value )
$\langle x, y \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle'$

As you see, their definition doesn't require positive definiteness.
Instead they define 'Semi definite', 'Positive', 'Negative' ... etc. as below

Semi definite inner product is an inner product that satisfies that the set $\{ x | \langle x, x \rangle = 0 \}$ is closed under vector space's operations( i.e. scalar multiplication, vector addition )
Positive inner product satisfies that $\langle x, x \rangle\ge 0$ for all $x$
Negative inner product satisfies that $\langle x, x\rangle \le 0$ for all $x$

They say that " semi definite inner product is either positive or negative inner product. ".
But I can't figure out how to prove it. Please someone help me.
( I proved the converse, that is " an inner product is positive or negative, then it is semi definite inner product. ". )

Hi and welcome to MSE! Please format the mathematics in your question using MathJax, here's a quick guide. Also, please show us what you've tried, how far you got and where you got stuck. Questions that don't show any own effort at solving their problem are generally not welcome here.

@BenSteffan Thanks for pointing out my fault. I'll keep that in mind.

Edit: The following proof works for both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ (both equipped with their usual partial order, $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with identity involution and $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with complex conjugation), but may not work otherwise. The claim is simply wrong in general for a field equipped with an involution and partial order - even if the field is $\mathbb{Q}$ and the involution is therefore necessarily identity. See the second segment of this answer.
Assume to the contrary that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is semi-definite, but neither positive nor negative. Then there exist vectors $x, y$ s.t. $\langle x, x \rangle < 0$ and $\langle y, y \rangle > 0$. Now, consider $ax + by$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Since the inner product is semi-definite, we must have,
$$\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \langle ax + by, ax + by \rangle = 0\}$$
is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However,
$$\langle ax + by, ax + by \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle a^2 + 2 \text{Re}(\langle x, y \rangle)ab + \langle y, y \rangle b^2$$
So, the set $\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \langle ax + by, ax + by \rangle = 0\}$, equivalently the set of all $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying the second order polynomial equation $\langle x, x \rangle a^2 + 2 \text{Re}(\langle x, y \rangle)ab + \langle y, y \rangle b^2 = 0$, is a degenerate conic. As $\langle x, x \rangle < 0$ and $\langle y, y \rangle > 0$, its discriminant is negative, so it is a degenerate hyperbola, i.e., two intersecting straight lines, which is not a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, a contradiction.

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be equipped with its standard order and where the involution is (necessarily) the identity map. I claim the result is simply false in that case. Indeed, let $V = \mathbb{Q}^2$ equipped with the inner product:
$$\langle (a, b), (c, d) \rangle = ac + \frac{1}{2}(ad + bc) - bd$$
It is easy to check that this is a symmetric bilinear form, so an inner product in the nLab sense. It is neither positive nor negative, since $\langle (1, 0), (1, 0) \rangle = 1 > 0$ and $\langle (0, 1), (0, 1) \rangle = -1 < 0$. However, it is semi-definite. Indeed, we have,
$$\langle (a, b), (a, b) \rangle = a^2 + ab - b^2 = (a + \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}b)(a + \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}b)$$
So $\langle (a, b), (a, b) \rangle = 0$ iff $a = -\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}b$ or $a = -\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}b$. But $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, so the only possibility is that $a = b = 0$. That is,
$$\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2: \langle (a, b), (a, b) \rangle = 0\} = \{(0, 0)\}$$
which is, of course, a linear subspace, so the inner product is semi-definite.
